# Downloading share prices directly in excel

Tags: excel, vba

Is there some sample code for downloading share prices and other stats (YTD performance in particular) directly into Excel?

Comment: Back on topic, how are you going with trawling through the string X to find the other pieces of information you want? Typically I use a break point in the code after X = .responsetext then I use the debug window to query X looking for the value I am after (Taken by manually opening the web page) then try to find reference points I can use to get that point of info. Yell out if you get stuck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was playing around with this stuff a few years back

```
Public Declare Function DeleteUrlCacheEntry Lib "Wininet.dll" _
Alias "DeleteUrlCacheEntryA" _
(ByVal lpszUrlName As String) As Long

Public Function getGoogPrice(symbol As String) As Variant
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim CompanyID As String
    Dim X As String, Y As Variant
    Dim sSearch As String
    strURL = "http://www.google.com/finance?q=" & symbol
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry (strURL)
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "get", strURL, False
        .Send
        X = .ResponseText
    End With
    symbol = UCase(symbol)
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    getGoogPrice = Split(Split(Mid(X, InStr(1, X, ":" & UCase(symbol) & """>" & UCase(symbol) & "</a><td class=price>"), 250), ">")(4), "<")(0)
End Function

Public Function getReutersPrice(symbol As String) As Variant
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Dim strURL As String
    Dim CompanyID As String
    Dim X As String
    Dim sSearch As String, myDIV As String, myPrice As String

    strURL = "http://www.reuters.com/finance/stocks/overview?symbol=" & symbol 'NESN.VX"
    DeleteUrlCacheEntry (strURL)
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    With xmlhttp
        .Open "get", strURL, False
        .Send
        X = .ResponseText
    End With
    Set xmlhttp = Nothing
    sSearch = "sectionQuoteDetail"
    myDIV = Mid(X, InStr(1, X, sSearch) + Len(sSearch))
    myDIV = Trim(Mid(myDIV, 1, InStr(1, myDIV, "</div>") - 1))
    Y = Split(myDIV, "</span>")
    myPrice = Mid(Y(1), InStrRev(Y(1), ">") + 1)
    myPrice = Replace(myPrice, Chr(13), "")
    myPrice = Trim(Replace(Replace(myPrice, vbLf, ""), Chr(9), ""))
    getReutersPrice = myPrice
End Function
```

Example try GetReutersPrice("MSFT") or GetGoogPrice("MSFT")

Whilst this gets the current price, everything you want should be on that page, scrape through for watever you are looking for.

Comment: +1, working on a project that will likely require `xmlhttp` so this serves as an excellent reference point